# Failed to load error while loading a template HTML file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a modal using components in AngularJS but it is throwing the error "Failed to load the HTML file".

How can I make that work?

It is also showing the following error: angular.js:14642 Error: [$compile:tpload]

and that too two times.

Any idea to make that work and if you can explain where did it went wrong. That would be highly greatful.

Here are my files.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Modal using Component</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="component.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class ="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logBTModal">What's New</button>
      <!-- Modal Starts -->
      <log-modal></log-modal>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
})();
```

**Component.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.component("logModal", {
  templateUrl: "logModalTemp.html",
  bindings: { name: '@'},
  controller: function(){
    this.title = "This is the first Modal that I have created!!"
  }
});
```

**LogModalTemp.html**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="logModalTemp.html">
<div id="logBTModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{$ctrl.title}}</h4>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: I previously saw an example where it was wrapped like this and it worked. Right now, when I place the LogModalTemp.html content in index.html, it works. Any idea, why it didn't worked previously.

Comment: try removing script tag around LogModalTemp.html and try.

Comment: It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

there is a small mistake.

check `templateUrl: "logModalTemp.html"` it should be `templateUrl: "LogModalTemp.html"`

Just for your reference https://plnkr.co/edit/0fAVzmQKiPX8junM3vxN?p=preview

Comment: I did that, but its still not working. Saying angular.js:12701 Failed to load file:///C:/Users/ShubhamBhatt/Desktop/Modal%20with%20components/logModalTemp.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Oh I can see a real problem now. you are running app without having a localserver running, angular use https for fetching templateUrl. you have to setup local server. use XAMP.

Comment: Yeah, got it now. Thanks.